# Zend framework 2 - where is public directory?

Tags: zend-framework2

I am reading zend 2 documentation on how to install:

https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/ref/installation.html

When I executed composer to install skeleton app, it installed 3rd version. Ok something is wrong with documentation.

Then I found I can download 2 version from here.

https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/releases/tag/release-2.4.10

Downloaded, ran

```
composer install
```

And I see folders: bin, library, resources, vendor. So where is public dir? Where is some file which should be run?

I tried to search for index.php, but only found one in library\Zend\Db\Sql\Ddl\Index

which does not look the one I need.

Answer (score 2):

Found between issues how to install.

https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/issues/370

Turns out I have installed something not full. Full is called skeleton application.

```
composer create-project -sdev zendframework/skeleton-application:^2.3 path/to/zf2-app
```